Pyrrhonian Skepticism
Pyrrhonian skepticism probably needs no introduction; Agrippa's Trilemma is a famous "unsolved problem".
I have some questions to ask on Pyrrhonism. No, SEP, IEP and Wiki don't have info on what I have doubts on.
According to Pyrrhonism, all pragmata are:

Adiaphora (logically undifferentiated)
Astathmeta (unstable)
Anepikrita (undecidable)

My questions are:

Are the translations in brackets accurate?
What do they mean?

Gracias.

The trilemma is not Agrippa's, he had 5 modes instead of 3, and addressed explanations or justifications rather than answering “what are things like by nature?”, as the three listed Pyrrhonian options do. SEP, Pyrrho does have a long passage on translations of these 3 terms and their meanings. They argue that "undifferentiable" is a more "perspicuous" translation for adiaphora, suggest that astathmêta might mean "unmeasurable" rather than unstable or unbalanced, and translate anepikrita as "indeterminate" or "indeterminable" instead.

@Conifold, thanks for the link to SEP. It seems that I've overlooked some of the sections. Are these archaic Greek words? None of my dictionary search results show that these presumably Greek words are used in modern Greek vernacular. I'm reading Sextus Empiricus' book on Pyrrhonism (a fourth of the way), and I don't see these concepts/words, which makes it even more puzzling. These are pronouncements, looks that way too, but I haven't come across either a book or article that delves into the reasons for them.

Adiaphora is still used commonly in theological contexts even in English, but with the meaning of moral or doctrinal indifference. The other two I have not seen outside of Pyrrhonian context. The discussion of what things are like by nature comes from Aristocles’ Peri Philosophias with reference to Timon rather than from Sextus. Sextus focused on later Pyrrhonists and Timon is closer in time to Pyrrho himself, with terminology distinct from theirs. There is evidence of Indian influence on Pyrrho as motivation, see Flintoff.

@Conifold, hoping to take this one at a time. What exactly does it mean that pragmata are adiaphora. If it means undifferentiated, is it akin to saying anatta (no-self) i.e. no identity?

@Conifold, second question. What does it mean that pragmata are astathemeta? Is it the same as the Buddhist anicca (impermanence)? Third question. What does it mean that pragmata are anepikrita? Is it analogous to Buddhist dukkha? The mapping isn't obvious to me.

Pyrrho himself unfolds it in Nagarjuna's spirit:"Neither our sense-perceptions, nor our doxai (beliefs) tell us the truth or lie; so we certainly should not rely on them. Rather, we should be adoxastoi (without beliefs), aklineis (uninclined toward this side or that), and akradantoi (unwavering in our refusal to choose), saying about every single one that it no more is than it is not or it both is and is not or it neither is nor is not." Mirovan discusses some implications of this in Pyrrhonism: Some Clarifications.

Those translations appear to be roughly adequate. You will find some references in several wiki pages:

Wiki: Adiaphora, things or issues that are neither good nor bad, "indifferent"
Wiki: Impermanence, "Pyrrho declared that everything was astathmēta (unstable), and anepikrita (unfixed)."
Wiki: Pyrrhonism, mentions the three terms

The analysis of Pyrrho's thought that Christopher Beckwith gives also confirms that those translations are more or less correct. He translates the comment of Timon of Phylus as:

As for pragmata ‘matters, questions, topics’, they are all adiaphora ‘undifferentiated by a logical differentia’ and astathmēta ‘unstable, unbalanced, not measurable’ and anepikrita ‘unjudged, unfixed, undecidable’."

He further clarifies "pragmata" as all disputed moral things, matters, affairs or topics. The term "adiaphora" is explained as "without self-identity":

The first term, adiaphora, is the negative of diaphora ‘differentiated by a logical differentia’ and literally means ‘undifferentiated by a logical differentia’, that is, ‘without a logical self-identity’.

Beckwith' explanation links those three terms with core concepts in Buddhism and suggests that Pyrrho may have learned them from Buddhist philosophy. This is at least a very interesting historical hypothesis, and it seems to lead to a not implausible interpretation. But translations of terms, across millenia and across different cultures is always tricky. Words like "logical" or "undecidable" have very specific meanings in contemporary philosophy; it's difficult to ignore those.
In the preface to his Xunzi translation John Knoblock, warning about the general difficulties and pitfalls of translation, writes:

Philosophical thinking by its nature is inquiry into the boundaries of knowledge -- departing from the established route of discourse, employing old words in new senses by analogically or metaphorically extending and pluralizing the meaning, creating new juxtapositions between words, forming new intersections of lines of inquiry, postulating a different nexus of thought, making radical erasures between contrary terms, and linking in a chain of arguments broad areas inquiry once regarded as isolated and unconnected. Under such conditions, it is easy to inderstand the difficulties that the lack of specific and well-informed context, if ever a clear context did exist, makes for any interpretation.
(Xunzi, A Translation and Study of the Complete Works, Vol III, 1994, p.ix)

If Beckwith is right, then we actually have a double translation. From Indian culture (Buddhism) to Greek philosophy to a current English translation.

Gracias. Acknowledging difficulties in translation, but I haven't found any open access resource that goes into the details. What I've encountered look like synonymous definitions (like the ones in the OP). No exposition accompanies them, and I thought skepticism was undergoing a revival in modern philosophy.  I was hoping for some kind of mapping to modern epistemological issues. Arigato gozaimus, your answer did clear matters up for me, even if not completely

The association with Buddhism, some find it remarkable, others think its just a coincidence. There's an attempted mapping between adiaphora, astathmeta, anepikrita to anicca, anatta, and dukkha. Which is which I wonder.

@Hudjefa - I'm also a bit sceptical - I do believe that there is a relevant similarity, but I wonder if it was really a simple transfer of concepts like Beckwith posits. His main argument seems to be that these concepts were so unprecedented in Greece... However, we also find similar ideas in 3d century Chinese thought (before Buddhism was known in China). So, some kind of convergent evolution of ideas in similar contexts is very well possible imo.

As to Pyrrhonism in a contemporary context - I liked Arne Naess' study of Sextus Empiricus ("Scepticism") - I cannot remember if he also explicitly comments on these terms but he does relate scepticism to the issue of having (or not having) a world view, to what could count as some kind of "philosophy of life". But this study is also already more than 50 yrs old...

A bygone era as someone keeps saying. If you come across an accessible (easy to read/understand) resources on these ideas, can you kindly post a link in here. Gracias.

Any crucial ways in which modern skepticism differs from ancient skepticism of Pyrrho et al?

Will do. Naess is extremely readable btw - he doesn't use the jargon or pedantic, scholastic style that lots of philosophers seem to like.

Fogelin, "Pyrrhonian Reflections on Knowledge and Justification" (1994) (https://academic.oup.com/book/36064?login=false)
-- I haven't read this, so don't know - but it does sound just what you want.
